# How to add string values of columns with a specific condition in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe in which there are a couple of columns and a lot of rows.

Now I want to create a new column (C) which adds values of another column (A) as a string together if a third column (B) is identical.

So each 'group' (that is identical in B) should have a different string than the other groups in that column in the end.

| A | B | New Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | First_Third |
| Second | 22 | Second_Fourth |
| Third | 1 | First_Third |
| Fourth | 22 | Second_Fourth |

Something like this pseudo code:

```
for x in df[B]:
if (x "is identical to" x "of another row"):
df[C] = df[C].cat(df[A])
```

How do I code an algorithm that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('_'.join)
```

Or, if you want to keep only unique values:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform(lambda x: '_'.join(x.unique()))
```

output:

```
        A   B              C
0   First   1    First_Third
1  Second  22  Second_Fourth
2   Third   1    First_Third
3  Fourth  22  Second_Fourth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform(lambda x: '_'.join(x))
```